# What are the arms for under the nozzle of NASA engine tests?

Tags: engines, identify-this-object, sls, ssme

When NASA tests rocket engines at the Stennis Space Center, the engines have two arms under the nozzle. When the engines start these arms swing out of the way of the exhaust. What are these arms for?

here is an RS-25 being tested. The arms are circled in red.[![here is an RS-25 being tested. The arms are circled in red.

[image: Annotated screenshot from the beginning of VideoFromSpace's January 21, 2024 NASA test-fires Artemis moon rocket engines for the first time in 2024 https://youtu.be/BVNzJ9f6Z9s]

Annotated screenshot from the beginning of VideoFromSpace's January 21, 2024 [NASA test-fires Artemis moon rocket engines for the first time in 2024](https://youtu.be/BVNzJ9f6Z9s)

Comment: Please link to the source of the image.

Comment: Organic Marble. Done, it’s a screen shot from YouTube.

Comment: [A video](https://youtu.be/xQx4-TER2Ak?t=506) which shows shutdown of the engine. I assumed that the arms are part of the fire suppression system and would swing back in after shutdown; apparently they _don't_.

Comment: It's new to me. I asked Stennis PAO; don't really expect an answer though.

Comment: Might be a camera rig to take high speed photos of the ignition but then needs to get out of the area before it burns... That thing at the end of the foil-covered wires looks kinda like a camera to me.

Comment: For a while there were a lot of papers about failure detection systems for the SSME that monitored the plume. I suspect this is something like that used for a quick shutdown if, for example, metal starts coming out of the engine at startup. But just a guess.